# How can I move a character in assembly text mode? (tasm x8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I have to do a little game using assembly for x8086 using tasm, is a maze-like game where I have to move some blocks in order to win the game. I have to read the maze from a .txt file and load it in the screen (it has to be 25x80 as standard), the problem is that I don't have any idea on how to "detect" a character from the txt. For example, the walls are represented by "0" and the character by a "&", so how can i make the character "&" to move when I press an arrow key? I already load the file and is shown in the screen, but i don't know how to move it. I have to do it in text mode, using int 10h and int 16h, thanks.

Comment: File is array of bytes. Content are 0-255 numbers, a "text" file is the same, using some text encoding to specify what those numbers mean. In your case you are probably working with ASCII encoding, so beginning of file containing `0.#.&.0` is sequence of bytes: 48, 46, 35, 46, 38, 46, 48. If you already did read the file into memory, you have these bytes in memory, and can work with them, just calculate address (the file definition of line decides how to calculate offset into array for particular [x,y]) and you can do for example `cmp byte ptr [bx],'&'` to compare value at `bx` with number 38.

Answer (score 1):

When the maze is already displayed on the 80x25 textscreen it's very simple to read the character.

First put the cursor where you would like to read (change the column and row numbers for the location that you're after):

```
mov dl, 40     ;Column number of the middle of the screen
mov dh, 12     ;Row number of the middle of the screen
mov bh, 0      ;Display page
mov ah, 02h    ;Function number
int 10h
```

Then read it:

```
mov bh, 0      ;Display page
mov ah, 08h    ;Function number
int 10h
```

Now you'll find the character code in the `AL` register.
The `AH` register will tell you the foreground and background colors of this character.

To test if this location contains your character, write:

```
cmp al, "&"
je  YES
```

To remove the character from the screen, just write a space to the screen:

```
mov cx, 1      ;Repetition count
mov al, " "    ;Character code
mov bh, 0      ;Display page
mov ah, 0Ah    ;Function number
int 10h
```

Comment: I wouldn't read the chars from video memory like this. It's slow even directly, and trough BIOS `int 10h` it is mega slow. I know it does not matter for text-mode game, but this should be showed only as "it's possible", not like recommending it. On PC XT machine it's much better either to have off-screen buffer in memory, or at least access the VRAM directly through b800:0000 address. Anyway, I find more alarming the OP doesn't understand how data are stored in computer memory, teaching him to read VRAM is way beyond these basics. (it's good answer, just 50x slower than correct solution)